# PHP: how can I add a specific title to my flash message?

Tags: php

I'm working on a flash message with PHP, but I would like to have a specific title for each of my flash message. My container for the flash message is set in my header.php so I can use this system everywhere on my site:

```
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION["flash-message"])): ?>
            <?php foreach($_SESSION["flash-message"] as $type => $message): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-<?= $type; ?>">
                <p><?= $message; ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

To execute it, I use this:

```
$_SESSION["flash-message"]["success"] = "Test";
```

So, I have that:

[image: http://prntscr.com/a2ylze]

Now, I would like to have a title, you know? Something like that:

```
$_SESSION["flash-message"]["title" = "The title"]["success"] = "The message"
```

Just something like that. I want the title above the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: use an array or object to store your message with corresponding title.

```
$_SESSION["flash-message"]["success"] = array("Title", "The Message");
```

And your code will be like following:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["flash-message"])): ?>
        <?php foreach($_SESSION["flash-message"] as $type => $message): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-<?= $type; ?>">
            <h2><?= $message[0]; ?></h2>
            <p><?= $message[1]; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT: 
And what happens if you have more than one success message? Your current code doesn't support multiple "same type" messages. It should be:

```
$_SESSION["flash-message"]["success"][] = array("Title", "The Message");
```

to store multiple "same-type" messages.

EDIT-2:
You can also use object approach - more readable. Also contains multiple message ability I mentioned above.

```
<?php 
    $message = new stdClass();
    $message->title = "Title";
    $message->message = "The Message";
    $_SESSION["flash-message"]["success"][] = $message;
?>
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["flash-message"])): ?>
    <?php foreach($_SESSION["flash-message"] as $type): ?>
        <?php foreach ($type as $message): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-<?= $type; ?>">
            <h2><?= $message->title; ?></h2>
            <p><?= $message->message; ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks! It is possible to have a specific variable for the title? I don't want to have $message[0] and $message[1]. I would like to have $title for the title and $message for the message.

Comment: Please see EDIT-2 in my answer. It is more "readable" by using a message class object. I used stdClass but you can even create your own custom message class for this. This is only a start point for you. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION["flash-message"]` should be an **array** of **messages**, and a **message** should have an *event_type*, a *title* and a *content*.

You can model messages in many forms, with **classes** or **associative arrays**. See this example *message* modeled with an associative array:

```
$a_message = [
    "event_type" => "success",
    "title" => "The title"
    "content" => "The message"
];
```

This way, you could implement your *foreach* loop like this:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION["flash-message"])): ?>
    <?php foreach($_SESSION["flash-message"] as $message): ?>
    <div class="alert alert-<?= $message["event_type"]; ?>">
        <h1><?= $message["title"]; ?></p>
        <p><?= $message["content"]; ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```